# Searching public posts misses pages

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api, fan-page

I have been experimenting with Facebook search to find posts from pages but this does not seem to be a supported feature. Neither the search results on facebook.com, when filtered with "Public posts", nor the search method in graph API, when filtered with "type=post", shows results from fan pages. Only posts from user walls show up.

I have tried with several different keywords and explicitly checked some fan pages for the existence of matching posts. The result was always the same, posts from pages done't show up in search results.

From the documentation I would actually conclude the opposite. On http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ it is written that https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post would find all public posts for query "watermelon".

Is this a shortcoming of the API or simply a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I ran a couple of test searches using different strings (trying to find one that would be common for pages such as "BREAKING NEWS") and didn't have any luck finding page results. As far as I can tell, this is truly a shortcoming of the Graph API. This is most likely due to the excessive bandwidth it would take to search pages and users at the same time, so Facebook must have decided to limit the API search to merely finding the posts of other users since this is what most applications would be needing access to.